# Informatica - Getting multiple records using Teradata stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata, informatica

I am trying to get a resultset from Teradata stored Procedure to my Mapping.

The stored procedure is to hold multiple select statements and the final output is to be sent to informatica. Below is a sample of how the select statement looks like

```
sel 'INH1' AS QC_CODE,count(*) from Table 1 
UNION
sel 'INH2' AS QC_CODE,count(*) from Table 2   
UNION
sel 'INH3' AS QC_CODE,count(*) from table 3
```

I need a stored procedure that can send the output of the above query (2 columns, 3 records) to Informatica, where I can call the stored procedure in my source qualifier or through SP transformation

Any help??

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `Stored Procedure` in `Source Qualifier` transformation using `SQL Query` property. Just make sure the ports, their order and datatypes reflect the columns returned by the Stored Procedure.